# How to show 3 nested tables in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I am looking for a way to combine 3 Tables:

```
Contract | Invoice | Payments
```

with relations 1:n between them, for example:

I have 3 sheets: `Contract`, `Invoice`, `Payments`, with IDs; for simplicity, shown below are only the ID columns:

```
Contract    Invoice      Payments
--------    -------      ---------
Contract1   Invoice10    Payment101
Contract1   Invoice10    Payment102
Contract1   Invoice11    Payment103
Contract2   Invoice12    Payment104
Contract2   Invoice13    Null
Contract3   Null         Null
```

I want to create **3 Linked Tables** in the **Same Page**:

When I select one `Contract`, the other tables only show data related to this `Contract`, and after I select one `Invoice`, then the table of `Payments` only shows data related to this `Invoice`.

The only way that I found about was blending 3 tables, however, I would need the same key fields (Join Keys) in all tables, but that is not in my case.

Comment: you want this in google sheets? pls share a copy/dummy of your sheet

Comment: I want make in Google Studio.. the data is store in google sheet....
I have two perspective.  


Single Table    

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RutnAXSI7lHeqEESzCztDTq8HtI60NbbZhMqHFb-PIo/edit#gid=249318555    
    
3 Tables    
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RutnAXSI7lHeqEESzCztDTq8HtI60NbbZhMqHFb-PIo/edit#gid=0)    
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RutnAXSI7lHeqEESzCztDTq8HtI60NbbZhMqHFb-PIo/edit#gid=716248246)    
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RutnAXSI7lHeqEESzCztDTq8HtI60NbbZhMqHFb-PIo/edit#gid=1339797862)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({A1:A, B1:B, C1:C}, 
 "where Col1='"&F1&"' 
    and Col2='"&F2&"'", 0), 
 "no match")
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mAxX2_vi8W3NCyszz8aP9c6Q5_UJXQst51UKCGjOEdA/edit#gid=1381056327)**